# iReport - How to change character spacing in text field?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to change character spacing in text fields in `iReport designer`? If not, is there any other solution with text formatting in `Java` or in something else? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `to change character spacing in text fields`?

Comment: I have text TEXT1234567890 and want to write it as T E X T 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0... Something like in MS Word, Font, Character spacing Tab.

Comment: I think you can look for a font or you can use the [`scriptlet`](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/scriptlet/index.html). In case the using of `scriptlet` you can implement method on Java that use space character, for example.

Comment: @JurajPolak: Did you find any solution? I need the same thing.

Comment: @sarwar026 No, we made it other way. If it is small text, for example 10 characters, it is possible to do it with substr..., one character = one field but when it is more complicated, I think coding is need...

Answer (score 3):

After years, there is still no support for this in the *Jasper studio*. So I did a dirty workaround. Insert tabs in between characters, e.g.

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".replace("","\t")
```

then you can control the tab size with textfield's paragraph property - `Tab Stop Width`

Tab Stop Width = 1px
[image: Tab Stop Width = 1px]

Tab Stop Width = 10px
[image: Tab Stop Width 10px]

Just beware of "real" tab handling.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this...

```
($F{TEXT}.split("")).join(" ")
```

in a text field or variable.  Then add a means of trimming the leading space.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different font file which has more character spacing . There is no explicit setting to do this in iReport.